# Companies and addresses MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I've got a database with 2 tables.

- companies
- addresses

These are my tables.
**Adresses**

- adress_id
- adress_adress
- adress_adressnumber
- adress_zipcode
- adress_city
- adress_postbus
- adress_country
- adress_building
- adress_unit

**Companies**

- company_id
- company_name
- company_adress_id
- company_postadress_id

A company can have a address but maby different postal address. I want to join these addresses in 1 query but when i join them only 1 address is shown because i think they're overlapping.
What can i do make this work? I'm really struggling.

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT * FROM companies as c JOIN adresses as a ON c.company_adress_id = a.adress_id JOIN adresses as postaddress ON c.company_postadress_id = postaddress.adress_id
```

Comment: If you are looking to get both Addresses i.e. _Company PostAddress_ and _Company Address_, you could do it by doing **union** or simple **OR** in the **join**


using **union** 

`SELECT 
 *
FROM
 Companies AS c
JOIN Adresses AS a ON (c.company_adress_id = a.adress_id) 

union 
SELECT
 *
FROM
 Companies AS c
JOIN Adresses AS a ON   (c.company_postadress_id = a.adress_id)` 



using simple **OR** in **JOIN** 

`SELECT
 *
FROM
 Companies AS c
JOIN Adresses AS a ON (c.company_adress_id = a.adress_id) or (c.company_postadress_id = a.adress_id)`

Comment: Thanks @MarshallMathers but it now says that i've got an error in my MySQL query.


SELECT * FROM Companies AS c JOIN Adresses AS a ON (c.company_adress_id = a.adress_id) union
SELECT * FROM Companies AS c JOIN Adresses AS a ON (c.company_postadress_id = a.adress_id) using simple OR in JOIN SELECT * FROM Companies AS c JOIN Adresses AS a ON (c.company_adress_id = a.adress_id) or (c.company_postadress_id = a.adress_id)

Comment: could you please do the table structure dump on those two tables? i did test it using the

`CREATE TABLE `Adresses` (
  `adress_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `memeh` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`adress_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`


and 

`CREATE TABLE `Companies` (
  `company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_adress_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_postadress_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
`
it worked with these structure

Comment: Here's a dump for these tables. http://pastebin.com/qq68nWNK

Comment: it was to do with case of the table names, changing the case sorts the syntax problem.

`SELECT
 *
FROM
 companies AS c
JOIN adresses AS a ON (
 c.company_adress_id = a.adress_id
)
UNION
 SELECT
  *
 FROM
  companies AS c
 JOIN adresses AS a ON (
  c.company_postadress_id = a.adress_id
 )`

**OR**

`SELECT  * FROM  companies AS c JOIN adresses AS a ON (c.company_adress_id = a.adress_id) or (c.company_postadress_id = a.adress_id)`

Comment: I've got a result now yes. But its not how i want i yet. Because i want the 2 results combined in 1 result.

http://pastebin.com/cxyffrfF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18832/discussion-between-mr-bear-and-marshall-mathers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            -- ---------------------------- 
            -- Table structure for adresses 
            -- ---------------------------- 
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `adresses`; 
            CREATE TABLE `adresses` ( 
            `adress_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
            `adress_adress` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
            `adress_adressnumber` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
            `adress_zipcode` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
            `adress_city` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
            `adress_postbus` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
            `adress_country` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
            `adress_building` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
            `adress_unit` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
            `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
            `addresss_role` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Role 1 for company may be and 2 for comapny postal, feel free', 
            PRIMARY KEY (`adress_id`) 
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; 

            -- ---------------------------- 
            -- Records of adresses 
            -- ---------------------------- 
            INSERT INTO `adresses` VALUES ('1', '1324234', '', '', '', null, '', null, null, '1', '2'); 
            INSERT INTO `adresses` VALUES ('2', '67856785678', '', '', '', null, '', null, null, '1', '1'); 

            -- ---------------------------- 
            -- Table structure for companies 
            -- ---------------------------- 
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `companies`; 
            CREATE TABLE `companies` ( 
            `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
            `company_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
            `company_adress_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
            `company_postadress_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
            PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`), 
            KEY `company_adress_id` (`company_adress_id`,`company_postadress_id`), 
            KEY `company_adress_id_2` (`company_adress_id`,`company_postadress_id`), 
            KEY `company_postadress_id` (`company_postadress_id`), 
            CONSTRAINT `address` FOREIGN KEY (`company_adress_id`) REFERENCES `adresses` (`adress_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
            CONSTRAINT `postal_address` FOREIGN KEY (`company_postadress_id`) REFERENCES `adresses` (`adress_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; 

            -- ---------------------------- 
            -- Records of companies 
            -- ---------------------------- 
            INSERT INTO `companies` VALUES ('1', 'sdfgsdf', '1', '2');
```

Comment: this structure supports the query in @Mr. Bear answer

Answer (score 0):

Best solution. Thanks to @Marshall Matters

```
SELECT
c.*,
a1.adress_adress AS company_adress_adress,
a1.adress_adressnumber as company_adress_adressnumber,
a1.adress_zipcode as company_adress_adress_zipcode,
a1.adress_zipcode as company_adress_adress_city,

a2.adress_adress AS postal_adress_adress,
a2.adress_adressnumber as postal_adress_adressnumber,
a2.adress_zipcode as postal_adress_adress_zipcode
a2.adress_zipcode as postal_adress_adress_city

FROM
companies c
INNER JOIN adresses a1 ON c.company_id = a1.company_id
AND a1.addresss_role = 1
INNER JOIN adresses a2 ON c.company_id = a2.company_id
AND a2.addresss_role = 2
```